# play querydsl plugin Limiting Qclass generation by package

Tags: jpa, playframework, sbt, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am using `play framework` version 2.2.0 and using `play-querydsl` plugin.
I am using `Spring Data JPA` version 1.7.2 integrated with `play framework`.
I am not using `querydsl` for all the model classes and only for few scenarios which are not supported by `Spring Data JPA` such as mixing more than one AND, OR checks in the WHERE clause.
Hence I would like to limit the generation of the `QClasses` by the `play-querydsl` plugin to few packages only and not all the packages which contain ENTITY classes.

I referred to https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl and added the `QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage` entry to my `build.sbt` as below :

```
playJavaSettings ++ QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLSettings
QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage := "com.codetroopers.app.models"
```

But after this, when I try to build the play app using activator, the Q classes are not getting generated. When I removed the `QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage` entry from my `build.sbt` file, the Q classes are generated normally for all ENTITY classes inside models package.
Is there a way to limit the Q class generation by the plugin to only few packages or to only package ?

Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out version 0.1.2 of the plugin -it's just been released. According to docs:

```
//From Play 2.3 and onward (thanks to autoImport feature)
queryDSLPackage := "com/codetroopers/app/models"
//OR Up to play 2.2
QueryDSLPlugin.queryDSLPackage := "com/codetroopers/app/models"
```

I'm using Play 2.3 and can confirm that it now works as expected (everything under com/codetroopers/app/models is scanned recursively).